# Retrieving data from DB

Tags: java, oracle

I have this table in oracle and i need to retrieve two columns from the table `desc_data` 
eg:

```
select ticket_id, date_logged from desc_data;
```

I would have around 10,000 records in this table, so if I do this operation from java and perform some operations in java by putting these values in a list and then based on some conditions filter data and insert back into some other table, would it be possible and if it's possible would it be an overhead?

Answer (score 2):

I think better to use a stored procedure in database and just call it from java. But what you consider is a possible solution too.

Comment: java can process as many records as long the memory can contain such number of records. For example, if you want to store 10,000 ints in memory you will need 10,000 * 4 bytes or, IOW, less than 4kb. All you need to check is heap space parameters passed to target jvm.

Comment: so u mean to say retreiving 10,000 records and then performin operations in java should not be a problem!!

Comment: as long as you have enough memory, yes, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of filtering you wish to do on your 10000 records. If the filtering is simple, such as filtering the records in a date range, then you can achieve that just using SQL. If your processing is more complex, then you could also use an stored procedure. As you are running on Oracle these can be written in Java. See [here](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3337411) for an example.

Comment: well i want to retrieve defect id's and their last updated time column and compare it a existing list i have in java

Comment: If the list that you currently have in Java was stored in another table, say we called it filter_table, then you could do the filtering you want with an inner join on the two tables. If the contents of filter_table don't change much between the times when you want to do this comparison, then it'll work well and be very quick. If the list of defect ids changes very regularly, then it would be best to do the filtering the way you have suggested, by retrieving the records from the desc_data table and doing the filtering in Java: with 10000 records it would probably take only a few seconds.

Comment: No the list which i have comes from  a excel sheet ..thats de whole problem :)

Comment: Then the Java approach is the way to go. The retrieve will be quick, but the inserts, as they'll be done one at a time in a loop will be the slow part. That said, with 10000 records in the table, I'd be surprised if it takes more than 10 seconds on a well tuned Oracle database.